# How to access a function embedded into another function from an external javascript file?

Tags: javascript

My apologies if this question have already been asked but for some reasons , I can not find pertinent answers.

so I have a `script X.js` that have two functions : `function B` embedded into a main `function A` , and an outside `script Y.js` that contains `function C`. Both scripts are located into the root folder.

**script X.js**

```
function A () {
  // code here ....

  function B () {
  // code here need to be accessed by function C () in script Y
  }

}
```

**script Y.js**

```
function C () {
  //code in function C that need to work with input from function B ...
}
```

My question is how can I get the output of `function B` directely into `function C ()` that is located in `script Y.js` ?

Comment: Ideally, you'd use something like Webpack to implement a proper module system, for a problem like this. But without that, why not just take B out of A so C can access it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance because B works with data  flowing from A

Comment: @wawa Then call `B` with the data from `A`: `B(a.data)`

Comment: you can't unless function B is the return from function A. function B does not exist at compile time so it would be impossible for the any compiler to link it. however if A = () => () =>{....} then the result of A() would be B

Comment: Can you show me an example of how would you do it ?

Comment: I fixed the problem by using parameters. Let me know if you still want to see how I managed to make it happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also import or export your function like so using 1 or 2

1. Use import / export if you are using ES6

scriptX.js

```
export function A() {
    function B() {
       return yourData;
    }

    return B();
};
```

scriptY.js

```
import { A } from './ScriptX';
    export function C() {
       return A();
    }
}
```

2. Requirejs module

// reference require.js in your html

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

scriptX.js

```
var A = function () {
    function B() {
      return yourData;
    }

   return B();
}

module.exports.A = A;
```

scriptY.js

```
var A = require('./scriptX');
function C() {
    return A();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't help answer the questions of accessing nested functions.

Comment: I was also be able to sove the problem by using `parameters`

Comment: @Lex You are right, but instead I am showing how function can be exported / imported. The nested function can also be moved out of function A and exported for use by ScriptY